# Windows Form button call button

Tags: c#, forms, button, panel

how do I get each click on the button to create a new button and put in the panel?.

I do not know what method to use to create array of button.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Button c = new Button();
        c.Location = new Point(15,40);
        c.Text = "novo";
        panel1.Controls.Add(c);


    }
```

Comment: by adding close to your title, you signify that the question was closed, in your case I believe you meant it was answered. That is what the green checkmark is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do create new button and add it to panel, just you create them all in SAME place.

```
c.Location = new Point(15,40);
```

You probably need some counter on class level for X or Y coordinate or for both.

```
public class Form1 : FOrm {

private int x = 15;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Button c = new Button();
        c.Location = new Point(x,40);
        c.Text = "novo";
        panel1.Controls.Add(c);

        x += 10 + c.Size.Width;
    }
}
```

You might want to check whether you are out of boundaries of form and to start at the beginning of "new row".

Answer (score 1):

you can create list of buttons like below

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<Button> ButtonList = new List<Button>();
```

then you can create buttons as you did

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button c = new Button();
        c.Location = new Point(10 , 40);
        c.Text = "novo";
        ButtonList.Add(c); // add to list as well 
        panel1.Controls.Add(c);       
    }
```

Note that you may want to change the location for each button otherwise all buttons are overlap and you only see one button which is on the top